# How to sort array of object by multiple field with different orders

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

I have an array of objects `Dog`. `Dog` has several fields:

- `name` (`String`)
- `color` (`String`)
- `kind` (`String`)

If I want to sort the array by `name`, `color`, and `kind` in ascending order, I can do:

```
dogs.sort_by { |dog| [dog.name, dog.color, dog.kind] }
```

but what if I want to reverse only by the first field, i.e.,

- `name` (descending)
- `color` (ascending)
- `kind` (ascending)

Is there any solution without introducing some hash representing `color` and `kind` by `Intergers` (we can apply `-` to integers when sorting)?

Comment: It can be achieved by `sort { |dog1, dog2| [dog2.name, dog1.color, ...] <=> [dog1. name, dog2.color, ...] }`

Comment: I added another solution to the cited duplicate.